# Wordpress striking theme child theme with git integration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to do heavy customization on the [Striking theme](http://themeforest.net/item/striking-premium-corporate-portfolio-wp-theme/128763) by adding styling and DOM elements to the pages such that they won't be affected on updates.

1. It seems that each theme update would overwrite all the php files (including the child folder?). Is there a way to maintain a typical child theme?
2. From reading the [support forum](http://kaptinlin.com/support/), it seems that custom styling is encouraged to be done in the custom css section that is stored in the wordpress database. However, I will be using version controlling in git, and the database will not be part of the git repo.
3. Will it be possible use the child's style.css such that it works and is retained on updates?
4. Since the styling of Striking is inside screen.css instead of the usual style.css, can I activate the child style.css the same way that Wordpress explains it in http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes ?

Answer (score 0):

1) the child theme folder is not within the parent theme, they are linked together by the Template clause in the child theme. Updating the parent won't affect the child

2) this is theme dependent, ask the author

3) yes, all themes must have a style.css

4) yes, see 3), the only issue here is the order that the css files will be included in.

All of this is a good reason not to use proprietary themes as parent themes for customization.  They are often complex and don't follow normal theme structure.  I usually start with the Toolbax or TwentyTwelve themes.  These are standard WordPress themes and are well behaved.